# How to make Identity unique to every table in SQL

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a database that generates each client user their own table,  in this table, I have an auto incrementer for the last entry in the table,  the problem i am having is that auto incrementar is also transferring to every table in the database where it should start from 1 for the new user.

Example: User 1 has a table with entry number set to 1 as first entry and 250 as last
User 2 has table with their first entry number starting at 251 (because it is continuing from user 1's table).

How can I make each entry column start at 1 for every user's table?  Looking online for this info to no avail.

Edit (overview of the application).
Each table respresents a users ("project list") user 1 creates a project and it assigns it to himself and it is entered in to the DB.

User2 creates a project but wants to assign it to user 1.  The project is inserted into his DB and User 1's datatable.  But in user1 table there is a column named 'Project Creator' which keeps track of the creator.

any user can assign any number of projects to any number of individuals (that have their own table).  It was the only easy I can think of doing this instead of having one big table.

Because projects can be assigned to 5 different users,  in which that case, those 5 different users get that project Info inserted into their table.

I just want to be able to query the tables and find when a new project has been added by IDing the last "entry" on every table.  the problem is the IDENTITY transfers to ever table therefore I can't keep track by comparing the last entry on every table since it Increments throughout all the users tables.

UPDATE:

I took someones advice on how its a bad idea to have a unique table for every user and decided to code everything using 1 huge table.  Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Simple:  don't have a separate table for every user.  That is a horrible way to design a database.

Comment: Is it some kind of partitioning? There is too little information in your question. Show us your table definitions. The easy answer is that if you are not happy with auto-increment, then use manual increment.

Comment: The design certainly looks problematic. Posting the table structure and maybe explaining why you made that peculiar design choice would allow more in-depth comments and possible suggestions for improvements. But this approach does not scale: the number of tables in any DBMS is usually limited.

Comment: Edited with the overview.  I am an SQL newbie so I am very appreciative with a thorough in-depth response.

Comment: Is the problem that you have 5 tables, and they all start at 1, or that you have 1 table or sequence, so that user 1 may get 1-3, user 2 gets 4-5 etc, depending on order of inserts?